# Eclipse CDT methods comments autogeneration using Doxygen style

Tags: eclipse, comments, doxygen, eclipse-cdt, auto-generate

Hope this is not a duplicate... It should not since I tried the usual provided fixes.

I'm facing problems with the automated generation of comments for `Classes` and `Methods` using Elipse CDT (Juno/3.8, Linux) configured with `Doxygen` as default `Documentation Tool`.

I still get empty comments area for methods parameters while typing **`/** + ENTER`** :

```
/**
 *
 */
```

Here is what I already tried without success :

- **Setting** : Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Documentation Tool Comments > Doxygen
- **Setting** : Project > Preferences > Enable Project Specific Settings > Doxygen

Both lead to the same result.

**Note** : not sure about what happened with Eclipse configuration (it used to work fine before). Is that possible that I erased the Doxygen presets (maybe by pressing `Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Code Templates > Restore Defaults`). In that case how to get it back to Doxygen style ?

**EDIT**: I've got some new on the subject...

Basically, it was a global change in my project (which actually is a `shared library`). For some cross-platform portability reasons, I had to add a `MACRO` before all my classes, like follows :

```
class LIB_CLASS LabOneOfMyClasses {
public:
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately, doing this seems to break CDT's ability to generate smart functions headers (`@param`, `@return`, ...). So removing temporarily the MACRO, allows to get ride of this disagreeable behavior. It is annoying and is something I should report to CDT's staff...

Note : In the end, it is handled properly in Doxygen, anyway.

If someone has a brilliant idea, something I missed, about that ?

Comment: Same issue.  I don't know what's causing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a compiler abstraction header to solve this issue. Define a custom symbol in eclipse for your build configuration. Go to `Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Symbols > GNU C/C++` in eclipse and define a new unique symbol like `#__ECLIPSE_CDT__`.

Than in the compiler abstraction header you can write the followings:

```
#ifdef __ECLIPSE_CDT__
#  define LIB_CLASS
#else
#  define LIB_CLASS <required normal content>
#endif
```

And if you consistently include this compiler abstraction header into your files than eclipse will expand LIB_CLASS to nothing while your compiler will find and use the proper definition.